# Работа через несколько сетевых интерфейсов одновременно в Android

Tags: android, сеть

Современные устройства на базе ОС Андроид зачастую имеют несколько сетевых интерфейсов: GPRS+, Wi-Fi, Ethernet (если есть usb-host и соответствующий свисток). Могут ли эти интерфейсы быть активными одновременно, а не в порядке какого-то приоритета?

Например, планшет подключён как пульт управления какой-нибудь сетью или каким-нибудь устройством через ethernet/usb-rndis/wi-fi, и в то же время он должен обмениваться данными с удалённым сервером через интернет по 3G/wi-fi?

И можно ли настроить несколько интерфейсов на одном физическом для каких-то подобных целей? (Например, 192.168.0.хх для работы как веб-сервер, 2.3.4.хх для общения с чем-то там ещё). Насколько помню, обычно в настройках какого-нибудь Wi-Fi ничего такого нет.